# GridFS: For writing files using 'put', is explicit 'with' block necessary?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

For writing large files in gridFS using `put()`, is it necessary to use context manager `with` ?
Looking at the documentation for `put()` [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/gridfs/index.html#gridfs.GridFS.put), calling `put()` is equivalent to doing,

```
try:
    f = new_file(**kwargs)
    f.write(data)
finally:
    f.close()
```

Does that mean open and close for file is done automatically and hence do not require without explicit need to?

Answer (score 0):

[`gridfs.GridFS.put` isn't a context manager](https://github.com/mher/pymongo/blob/1.11/gridfs/__init__.py#L78). It doesn't define `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of the context management protocol.

Using it directly without some modification as a context manager will result in an `AttributeError`.

Using `gridfs.GridFS.put` as-is saves you few lines of code and more importantly having to manage opening and closing the `GridFile`.